# What is the '<' doing in this line?: data += dt < b

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, operators

Input:

```
dt    = [6,7,8,9,10]
data  = [1,2,3,4,5]

b     = 8.0
b     = np.require(b, dtype=np.float)

data  += dt  < b
data
```

Output:

```
array([2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```

I tried to input different number but still couldn't figure out what's the "<" doing there....
Also, it seems to work only when b is np.float (hence the conversion).

Comment: Perhaps you should read the numpy documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<` with numpy arrays does an element-wise comparison. That means it returns an array where there is a `True` where the condition is true and `False` if not. The `np.require` line is necessary here so it actually uses NumPy arrays. You could drop the `np.require` if you converted your `data` and `dt` to `np.array`s beforehand.

Then the result is added (element-wise) to the numeric array. In this context `True` is equal to 1 and `False` to zero.

```
>>> dt < b  # which elements are smaller than b?
array([ True,  True, False, False, False])

>>> 0 + (dt  < b)  # boolean arrays in arithmetic operations with numbers
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

So it adds 1 to every element of `data` where the element in `dt` is smaller than 8.

Answer (score 2):

`dt` is a list:

```
In [50]: dt    = [6,7,8,9,10]
In [51]: dt < 8
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-3d06f93227f5> in <module>()
----> 1 dt < 8

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

`<` (`.__lt__`) is not defined for lists.

But if one element of the comparison is an `ndarray`, then the numpy definition of `__lt__` applies.  `dt` is turned into an array, and it does an element by element comparison.

```
In [52]: dt < np.array(8)
Out[52]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
In [53]: np.array(dt) < 8
Out[53]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
```

numpy array operations also explain the `data +=` part:

```
In [54]: data  = [1,2,3,4,5]          # a list
In [55]: data + (dt < np.array(8))    # list=>array, and boolean array to integer array
Out[55]: array([2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
In [56]: data
Out[56]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [57]: data += (dt < np.array(8))
In [58]: data
Out[58]: array([2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```

Actually I'm a bit surprised that with the `+=` `data` has been changed from list to array.  It means the `data+=...` has been implemented as an assignment:

```
data = data + (dt <np.array(8))
```

Normally `+` for a list is a concatenate:

```
In [61]: data += ['a','b','c']
In [62]: data
Out[62]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c']
# equivalent of: data.extend(['a','b','c'])
```

You can often get away with using lists in array contexts, but it's better to make objects arrays, so you do get these implicit, and sometimes unexpected, conversions.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an alias (or shortcut or convenience notation) to the equivalent function: [**`numpy.less()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less.html)

```
In [116]: arr1 = np.arange(8)
In [117]: scalar = 6.0

# comparison that generates a boolean mask
In [118]: arr1 < scalar
Out[118]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False])

# same operation as above 
In [119]: np.less(arr1, scalar)
Out[119]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False])
```

---

Let's see how this boolean array can be added to a non-boolean array in this case. It is possible due to *type coercion*

```
# sample array
In [120]: some_arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# addition after type coercion 
In [122]: some_arr + (arr1 < scalar)
Out[122]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])

# same output achieved with `numpy.less()`
In [123]: some_arr + np.less(arr1, scalar)
Out[123]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
```

So, *type coercion* happens on the boolean array and then addition is performed.